# Cypress.io best practices, common selectors support file?

Tags: cypress

Reading through the documentation for best practices I don't see any mention of using a support file for all selectors to improve maintainability. 
Maybe this is a really simple question but what is the best practice for this in Cypress? Should I create a common constants file to pass into every test or declare these selectors in the commands.js file?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but I have not seen it done this way before. If you have the same selector in several files, perhaps making it a command would work. I did not down vote you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a long answer, but if I just said "keep them in the spec file" without the rest of the explanation it'd be bad advice.

Instead of doing a shared selectors file, what I have found great success with is keeping selectors in the spec files as a `const` object at the top, but making the spec files specific to a page/url.  That way there is no need to duplicate the selectors because all actions that use that selector will exist in one file.

There are a few exceptions, but in general any time a test navigates to a new URL the test will assert whatever work has been done, that the URL has updated, and the test will be over.  If another test requires setup to be done on a different page we will set up that state programmatically via API requests or stubbing network requests, then that test will begin by navigating directly to the URL of the page it will be testing.

There are components that are shared across several pages and might be used in multiple specs, like a navigation bar, header, or footer.  We will create a class that contains the actions and selectors for that component, then use that class instead of duplicating the actions and selectors in several different specs.

Example:  If your test is "User can edit their profile" with the steps:

`user-profile-spec.js`:

- log in
- click profile from navigation bar
- click "edit" button in profile page
- upload new profile photo
- edit profile information
- save
- assert all fields and profile photo are updated

It will become:

`home-page-spec.js`:

- log in in the `before()` via shared custom command `cy.login(username, password)`
- `cy.visit("/home")` in the `beforeEach()`

"User can navigate to profile page"

- Click "Profile" to access profile
- Assert that navigation to `/profile` was successful

`profile-page-spec.js`:

- log in in the `before()` via shared custom command `cy.login(username, password)`
- `cy.visit("/profile")` in the `beforeEach()`

"User can navigate to edit profile page"

- Click "Edit Profile"
- Assert that navigation to `/profile/edit` was successful

`edit-profile-page-spec.js`:

- log in in the `before()` via shared custom command `cy.login(username, password)`
- `cy.visit("/profile/edit")` in the `beforeEach()`

"User can edit profile fields"

- Edit some fields
- Click Save
- Use `cy.route` to assert that the request was fired to update the profile in the backend

"User can change profile photo"

- Upload new photo
- Use `cy.route` to assert that the request was fired to update the photo in the backend

This seems like more work up front but having the setup steps tested explicitly only once and avoided everywhere else means if it is broken you'll get only one test failure for `User can navigate to profile page` - which is obvious, but have the rest of the tests pass.  You'll also be able to quickly reference selectors because they exist in the same places they are used.  All this means easy maintainability and test failure investigation - key for UI tests.